# What does "ndvi is not defined" mean?

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat-5

I'm trying to apply the ndvi function on Google Earth Engine but it shows up the following error:

> ndvi is not defined

This is what I have written:

```
var L5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA"),
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon
var visL5 = B3,B2 and B1 from 0.031541384756565094 to 0.7842386960983276

var imagen = L5.filterBounds(geometry)
               .filterDate('2010-12-01','2011-03-31')
               .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than', 8);

var addNDVI = function(imagen) {   
var ndvi = imagen.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3'])
                 .rename('NDVI');
    return imagen.addBands(ndvi); };

Map.addLayer(ndvi,{},'NDVI'); --> here is where the error is ("ndvi is not defined").
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You need to map the `addNDVI` function to the image collection stored in `image`. You might want to read about the scope of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jhonathan said, you need to map the collection. So far, `ndvi` is a function variable, not a global variable. With `map()`, the function iterates the whole collection adding NDVI:

```
var addNDVI = function(imagen) {   
var ndvi = imagen.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3'])
                 .rename('NDVI');
    return imagen.addBands(ndvi); };

var imagen_ndvi = imagen.map(addNDVI)
Map.addLayer(imagen_ndvi,{bands: ['NDVI'],min: -1, max: 1, },'NDVI');
```

Also, I set some configuration parameters for you

By the way, I strongly recommend use another objectname here:

```
var imagen = L5.filterBounds(geometry)
               .filterDate('2010-12-01','2011-03-31')
               .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than', 8);
```

Since `imagen` is defined as a collection and a function variable, use other names, such as: col, collection, coleccion, whatever you want.